# WordPress title no showing with rest api using vue.js

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, posts

I am trying to use vue.js to display my posts but when I view the page nothing shows.

My app.js file looks like this:

```
var App = Vue.extend({});
var postList = Vue.extend({
    template:'#post-list-template',
    data: function(){
        return {
            posts: ''
        }
    },

    ready: function(){
        posts = this.$resource('/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=20');

        posts.get(function(posts){
            this.$set('posts', posts);
        })
    }
})

var router = new VueRouter();
router.map({
    '/':{
        component: postList
    }
});
router.start(App, '#app');
```

I have all the external resources such as vue-resource.js,router and vue.js.

My index.php looks like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="white-wrap">
        <div id="app">
            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
    </div>

    <template id="post-list-template">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="post-list">
                <article v-for="post in posts" class="post">
                    <div class="post-content">
                        <h2>{{ post.title.rendered }}</h2>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

When I inspect the page I it looking like this:

[image]

For now I was just trying with the title, but how can I display my posts using vue.js?

Is there something missing in my code/files?

I use wp-json/wp/v2/posts to view the rest api response and it looks like this:[image]

Comment: which version if vue are you using?

Comment: Paste here your full response from the rest api then only could answer

Comment: @Vamsi Krishna I just downloaded the latest version

Comment: @GNANA I do not quite follow what you mean when you say full response from rest api

Comment: @WosleyAlarico When you hit this url /wp-json/wp/v2/posts (wp rest api request) you will get json response, For example you hit in browser like below mentioned url in your wp site,   < your site name >/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

Comment: @GNANA I just edited my question. As you can see I have all the json data showing

Comment: @WosleyAlarico, your response have title, but when you use vue.js and print its missing. Did you get any other than title using this vue.js ? if yes means paste here that code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147451/discussion-between-wosley-alarico-and-gnana).

Answer (score 0):

1. As you said you are using the latest vue version there is no more `ready` lifecycle hook, you can use the `mounted` hook instead. See [Vue lifecycle hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks).
2. There is a scoping issue for `this`. The `this` you use in your `ready` function does not point to the vue instance. Use a fat arrow function instead or setup a variable pointing the correct vue instance and use that variable
3. Since you initialized `posts` property in you data property there is no nedd to use `Vue.set`

All put together

```
mounted: function(){
        var self = this;
        posts = this.$resource('/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=20');

        posts.get(function(posts){
            self.posts = posts;
        })
    }
```

Comment: Actually, I was using version 1.0.18 before. Only today I changed to the latest version since I was asked in the comment here. I just copied and pasted your code but the result is the same.

Comment: @WosleyAlarico what is your api url?

Comment: Do not quite understand the expression. What does an api url mean?

Comment: @WosleyAlarico the url you get the posts from?

Comment: I will manage to upload the site onto a test server. and will send it to you in  a few minutes. hope you are still here by then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147449/discussion-between-wosley-alarico-and-vamsi-krishna).

Answer (score 0):

[Data Fetching](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/data-fetching.html)

1. Fetching After Navigation **created** hook
2. Fetching Before Navigation **beforeRouteEnter** hook